# Watch and reaload for polymer serve / polyserve?

Tags: polymer, reload, watch, polymer-cli, serve

I'm trying to figure out a way to make [polyserve](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polyserve) / [polymer-cli](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) to reload my browser each time a "watched" file changes but I haven't found anything apart of adding [Livereload](http://livereload.com/) to the HTMLs files that I think is going to be a mess due that when developing web components I load separate HTML files.

Comment: There's a [PR](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polyserve/pull/135) in progress for this feature. You could wait for that to land, or update your build to use `gulp` and add a live reload plugin (such as [`browsersync`](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp)). You could also peek at [Polymer Starter Kit 1.3.0](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/releases/tag/v1.3.0) (old) to learn from their `browsersync` usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For auto reloading using Polymer CLI as a server in your project you should have [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) / [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) installed. Then you need to install [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/) locally.

`npm install -D browser-sync`

or

`yarn add browser-sync --dev`

Your `package.json` file will need to look something like:

```
{
  "name": "MY-ELEMENT",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run watch",
    "serve": "polymer serve --port 8080",
    "test": "polymer test",
    "watch": "browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080 --open --startPath \"components/MY-ELEMENT\" --files \"**/*.html\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13"
  }
}
```

(If its a regular Polymer app you should remove the `--startPath` argument as that is for Polymer component development)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. If anybody run the server under https like me remember to pass `--https` to `browser-sync` to work properly.

Comment: If someone is using polymer-cli and request for live-reload, I think that means he/she already has `npm` or `yarn` installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `polyserve-watch` which watches, serves and reloads webcomponents using polyserve and browser-sync``.

Best regards

Comment: polymer-watch Unpublished On Sat Aug 15 2020 15:53:36 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/polyserve-watch.

Comment: Yes you don't need it anymore. I have unpublished it because you have a lot of better tools like es-dev-server